# CodeIgniter inner join 3rd table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a small trouble trying to add the 3rd table.

this is the Table Structure:

```
products = 
id  name    code
5   product1    002
522 product1    002

warehouses = 

id  code    name    address     city
1   store1  store1  store1    store1

warehouses_products = 

id  product_id  warehouse_id    quantity
2       5           1             -3
3       522         1             -2
4       446         1              0
```

Here is the function getting the data:

```
    $this->load->library('tables');
           $this->tables
                ->select("products.id as productid, name, code (CASE WHEN sum(warehouses_products.quantity) Is Null THEN 0 ELSE sum(warehouses_products.quantity) END) as totalQuantity, warehouses.name");
                $this->tables->from('products');
                $this->tables->join('warehouses_products', 'products.id=warehouses_products.product_id', 'left');
                $this->tables->join('warehouses', 'warehouses_products.id=warehouses.warehouse_id', 'left');

$this->tables->group_by("products.id");
$this->tables->unset_column('productid');

echo $this->tables->generate();
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: There is no error, i cannot load the data in datatable. the result is blank.

Comment: Is there `table1.column_id` in `table1`? because I see you use `table1.id` in `select`

Comment: Yes, column1 and column2 is in table1

Comment: I mean `column_id`. or can you paste your tables' struct

Comment: what do you mean doesn't make any sense?, i missed to put some data in table to be more specific, but now i have updated this. and maybe now make sense what i need to do.

Comment: i want to get the name of store from where is located the product.

Answer (score 1):

your join query looks fine.. just that i noticed(if not worng) you have a `,` instead of `.`
in your select query..
try this

replace this..

```
$this->tables->select("table1.id as table1id, column1, column2, table2.column1, table3,column2")
```

with

```
$this->tables->select("table1.id as table1id, column1, column2, table2.column1, table3.column2") //notice the '.' here table3.column2
```

and also make sure(check) if the query that you are running is correct.. you can do this by printing  the last runned query in CI..

```
 echo $this->db->last_query();exit; //after query is made ..
```

and your updated question .. the join is incorrect..

**updated**

this

```
$this->tables->join('table2', 'table3.product_id=table1.id', 'left');
$this->tables->join('table3', 'table2.id=table3.warehouse_id', 'left');
```

replace with

```
$this->tables->join('table3', 'table3.product_id=table1.id', 'left'); //join the thrid table first
$this->tables->join('table2', 'table2.id=table3.warehouse_id', 'left');//and thn the second table with third tables warehouse_id
```

Comment: i have updated the query and added table structure for a better understand

Comment: Hello bipen, i have echo $this->tables->generate(); and if i add echo $this->db->last_query();exit; remain still in processing, loading data from server, because there is a server side request.

Comment: yes you can check the last query made in firefox firebug inside net panel....anywasy i updated my answer according to your updated question please try that too..

Comment: the result is SELECT * FROM (`settings`) ??

Comment: have u tried the updated part in my answer... i think that should work

Comment: im trying but no result. :(

Comment: this is getting interesting... did try printing the last query `echo $this->db->last_query();` just after the table->generate()..

Comment: yes, look, i have updated the question with your solution. maybe you can understand better now.

Comment: the last query is SELECT * FROM (settings)